# Accessing Azure Sql server from anywhere/VSTS Pipeline

Tags: sql, azure, azure-devops, azure-sql-database, azure-pipelines

I have a VSTS pipeline I use to deploy my API to Azure. In the deployement I have a  task for DBUpMigration. Whenever it runs it is unable to connect to my Azure hosted SQL server. I can access the SQL server from my management studio, but to do that I need to add my IP as a firewall exception. My problem is I do not know from what IP the pipeline is trying to access the SQL server. My question is, how can I find the pipeline IP or set a rule that allows the SQL server to be accessable from anywhere?

P.S. As long as I am able to deploy the database automatically, I do not care about security or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

Your proposed solution is a problem as it is not possible to "allow all" on SQL Azure.

There are a number of solutions for your problem, depending on the technology you use.

If you use entity framework (core) for ASP.NET (core), you can run the migration from code with `DbContext.Database.Migrate`.

An alternative is to create a Database Project in Visual studio containing the database structure. You can deploy this through VSTS and it will migrate the database where neccesary.

Calling upgrades straight from VSTS Pipelines (through powershell or some other task) won't work.

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out my Api and SQL Server were not in the same resource group, so that is why they could not reach each other.